# What's the reason for "header specification is not a regular expression: InvocationTargetException"

Tags: maven, checkstyle

I'm running the `maven-checkstyle-plugin` 2.15 with the following specification of a header check

```
<module name="RegexpHeader">
    <property
        name="header"
        value="^&lt;!--\n    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more\n   contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with\n   this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.\n   The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0\n   (the &quot;License&quot;); you may not use this file except in compliance with\n   the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at\n\n        http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0\n\n   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software\n   distributed under the License is distributed on an &quot;AS IS&quot; BASIS,\n   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.\n   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and\n   limitations under the License.--&gt;.*"/>
    <property name="fileExtensions" value="xml"/>
</module>
<module name="RegexpHeader">
    <property
        name="header"
        value="^/**\n * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more\n * contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with\n * this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.\n * The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0\n * (the &quot;License&quot;); you may not use this file except in compliance with\n * the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at\n *\n *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0\n *\n * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software\n * distributed under the License is distributed on an &quot;AS IS&quot; BASIS,\n * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.\n * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and\n * limitations under the License.\n */"/>
    <property name="fileExtensions" value="java"/>
</module>
```

What could cause the error `line 1 in header specification is not a regular expression: InvocationTargetException`? There's nothing to try because the plugin doesn't tell what's actually wrong (could return parser error details or anything helpful).

The complete error is

```
Failed during checkstyle configuration: cannot initialize module RegexpHeader - Cannot set property 'header' in module RegexpHeader to '^/**\n * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more\n * contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with\n * this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.\n * The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0\n * (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with\n * the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at\n *\n *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0\n *\n * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software\n * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,\n * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.\n * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and\n * limitations under the License.\n */.*': line 1 in header specification is not a regular expression: InvocationTargetException -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Maven plugin is just a wrapper over checkstyle library, all errors come from library, please try to reproduce a problem by running checkstyle directly , see example at chapter “ Download And Run

" at http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/cmdline.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The acutal reason where some unescaped characters, like `*` in the regular expression.

The feedback of `checkstyle` which is invoked by the `maven-checkstyle-plugin` isn't too great. I improved the code to reveal the error message of pattern compilation and requested merge at https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/pull/897.